# Generate qr-code with event machine

Tags: ruby, qr-code, eventmachine

I'm developing API, based on EventMachine echo server. It listens requests on specific port and returns html-page with qr-code on it, which is generated depending on params from request query. The problem is that evaluating method, which packs string into qr-code takes from 8 to 11 seconds, it is unacceptable. I have no ideas why it happens, except it could be associated with event-machine.

P.S. In irb the same code `RQRCode::QRCode.new(my_string, :size => 10,:level => :l)` takes less than 1 second.

I have tried two different gems: rqrcode and barby+rqrcode. Both show the same results.

Code example:

```
require 'eventmachine'
require 'rqrcode'

class Handler < EventMachine::Connection

  def receive_data(data)
    puts Time.now
    qrcode = RQRCode::QRCode.new('some_string', :size => 10,:level => :l)
    puts Time.now
    return qrcode
  end
end

EventMachine::run {
  EventMachine::start_server("0.0.0.0", 8081, Handler)
  puts "Listening..."
}
```

Output:

```
2015-05-12 18:03:38 +0300
2015-05-12 18:03:48 +0300
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I've run server in debug-mode from RubyMine. Starting server from console solves the problem, qr-code generation takes about 1 sec.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to call `close_connection`. Here's EventMachine's [echo server example](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine#server-example-echo-server)

```
 require 'eventmachine'

 module EchoServer
   def post_init
     puts "-- someone connected to the echo server!"
   end

   def receive_data data
     send_data ">>>you sent: #{data}"
     close_connection if data =~ /quit/i # <---- This is what you're missing -----
   end

   def unbind
     puts "-- someone disconnected from the echo server!"
   end
end

# Note that this will block current thread.
EventMachine.run {
  EventMachine.start_server "127.0.0.1", 8081, EchoServer
}
```

If your timestamps are always (nearly) exactly 10 seconds apart, I'd wager the request is ending because of a timeout rather than because of a response. After you respond with the QR data, call `close_connection` to let the browser know you're finished properly.

**Edit** It also looks like you're not calling `send_data` (and referencing `Tume` instead of `Time`). It looks like you need to use `send_data`, not `return`. Is your code snippet what's actually running on your server?

**Update** Running in debug mode was significantly slowing down QR generation.

Comment: I know how it works and I know about close_connection. The problem is that `RQRCode::QRCode.new` takes about 10 seconds to complete. As you can see I have put `puts Time.now` before and after it and showed it's output. It's very simplified example only to demonstrate the problem

Comment: Since it's fast in irb, can you post your actual slow code so we can see what's going on or try to reproduce it?

Comment: Kristján, I have posted already, in `code example` block. You can copy that and run on your machine, then look at output, how much seconds is the difference between first and second time

Comment: You said it's a simplified example, so it might not contain the problem you're seeing; and `Tume` isn't a thing, so this clearly isn't what's running.

Comment: Your example code on my computer generates the QR code instantaneously, and then nothing happens on the connection. `send_data qrcode` successfully gets the data back to my telnet session the way you'd expect.

Comment: Thank you. I have run it in debugging mode in Rubymine. This way code works very slow, when I have simply run it from console, generating qr-code takes about 1 sec